# Erro ao carregar múltiplos swf no html

Tags: html, asp.net, flash

Criei um relatório em *ASP.NET* e *HTML* que carrega arquivos .*swf* (*flash*) dentro de um *for*.

O problema é quando o for é grande e ele precisa carregar vários arquivos .swf no mesmo relatório o flash simplesmente não é executado e fica com uma marcação de uma exclamação (!) como podem ver na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código de como é realizado o carregamento do .*swf*:

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        id="painelv3" width="100%" height="100%"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="meuArquivoFlash.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="<% =flashvar %>" />
        <embed src="<% =sUrl %>" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"
            width="800" height="800" name="meuArquivoFlash" align="middle"
            play="true"
            loop="false"
            quality="high"
            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
        </embed>
    </object>
```

Answer (score 2):

Este ponto de exclamação cinza, também conhecido como *GCOD* (*Gray Circle of Death*, ou Círculo Cinza da Morte, em tradução livre), surge quando o Flash Player está requisitando mais memória do que o navegador tem disponível. Caso este alerta não existisse, o navegador seria encerrado pelo Sistema Operacional, por falta de memória. É um problema que tem de ser sanado na sua aplicação e, por isso, posso apenas sugerir soluções:

A aplicação Flash poderia ser aperfeiçoada para que menos recursos fossem utilizados, possibilitando o carregamento de mais instâncias na mesma página.

Se a aplicação Flash utiliza muitos recursos, mas apenas em sua inicialização, esta poderia se comunicar com a página através de JavaScript e `ExternalInterface`, para que a próxima instância fosse iniciada somente após a conclusão da anterior.

Além disso, ao invés de carregar múltiplas instâncias da mesma aplicação Flash na página, os dados poderiam ser passados para uma única instância, que se encarregaria de exibir múltiplos itens.

Outras soluções podem ser implementadas na página, sem ter que alterar a aplicação Flash—como paginação—e algumas, com a ajuda de JavaScript—como habilitar apenas as instâncias que estão visíveis na tela, semelhante à páginas que utilizam vídeos e rolagem infinita.

O aviso de erro de memória foi introduzido no Flash Player 10.1 e mais informações podem ser acessadas no Blog Oficial da Adobe (em inglês): http://blogs.adobe.com/dekesmith/2012/06/07/what-is-the-gray-circle-with-an-exclamation-mark-or-bang/

Comment: Amigo, já tinha lido sobre isso nesse link que vc mandou. Vou dar um upvote, porém vou deixar a pergunta em aberto para ver se alguém tem alguma solução que possa minimizar meu problema.